# FTP Sites vs Sites in IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, ftp

We have one FTP site set up (and working) basically like the instructions here: 
http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/creating-a-new-ftp-site-in-iis-7
It shows up under "Sites" and then the name of our FTP Site.

However, above "Sites" (in the left navigation tree view), we see a node called "FTP Sites".  When we click on it, it says "FTP Management is provided by IIS 6.0".

Can someone give me the big picture of why this node appears, and why IIS 6 is involved?  Is is some backward compatible feature?  I didn't build these machines, so don't know the reasoning of what was done before I arrived on the scene.

Also, is the tree view icon for websites and FTP sites the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Windows Server 2008 shipped, originally, the FTP functionality in IIS wasn't rewritten from the Windows 2003 IIS 6.0 FTP service, and the IIS 6.0 metabase and management tools were necessary for FTP functionality.

Microsoft [shipped FTP 7.0 and 7.5 later on](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-ftp-7-on-iis-7) as add-on installations to Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2.

It sounds like you've still got the stock IIS 6.0 FTP service installed, along with the new IIS 7.0 FTP service. I wasn't actually aware that you could have both installed at the same time, but that's my best guess.

Comment: Thanks, so with 7.0 technique, when you see a list of sites, you have no idea which ones are FTP and which ones are Web? The icons are the same?

Comment: So would it be advisable to remove IIS 6 now? Under "Remove Features" "Remote Server Admin Tools", "Role Admin Tools", "Web server (IIS) Tools"?

Comment: @NealWalters - Yes-- they do have the same icon. Highlighting the "Sites" container and looking at the "Status" or "Binding" columns are your best way to tell them apart. Having never removed the IIS 6 components from an operating IIS 7 FTP server I can't really say that it will or won't cause problems. If you have a test machine to try it on (or can restore a backup of this machine and test it there) that would be your best bet.